# Avoid edges intersection in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, drawing, draw

How could I avoid edges intersection in a graph?

> 1 the graph is a tree
>
> 2 the nodes may have at most 4 children
>
> 3 I may draw the node at any distance from its parent

Here is an example of my graph:

[image]

So, my idea is to draw the graph from the left to right node by node, edge by edge and when I encounter the branching I should undertake some actions (move previous branchings further apart, I consider previous nodes to be those nodes which are reachable from the current node if we will move only in the direction of the root (on the image above the root is the Start - leftmost node) ).

And here is the problem: by only modifying the previous nodes it is still possible to get an intersection of edges. For example, on the previous image if I will add a node to the rightmost upper end, then all the previous nodes won`t even need any modifications (to prevent the intersection), but the intersection happens.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=3A013A211737A56256D8A895B937DBDF?doi=10.1.1.51.6677&rep=rep1&type=pdf has a linear time algorithm to draw a planar graph on a grid without any edges intersecting.  Does that work for you?

Comment: Broken link.  Does anyone know the title for this paper so we can search for it?

Comment: @DaveP. The title is *A Linear-time Algorithm for Drawing
a Planar Graph on a Grid* and the link works for me.